# Show message if HTML5 video couldn't be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I display a message if a HTML5 video in a certain browser couldn't be loaded?

We have two different file-types: `.mp4` and `.webm`. Then I want to display an error message, if the video couldn't be loaded.

If we for example takes Firefox. It only support `.webm`, and if that `.webm-file` is missing, the filename misspelled or the file is in some way not working, I want the message to appear.

If we then takes Chrome. It supports both files, so here the message, should only appear if both of the files are missing, misspelled or not working.

So basically the message should only appear, if there is no way of playing the video at all.

I have tried to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        function checkLoad() {
            if (video.readyState === 4) {
            }
            else {
                alert("Not Loaded!");
            }
        }

        checkLoad();
    }, false);

});
```

But that did't worked well in Firefox...

Hope you can see what I mean, and that you can help. :)

Thanks - TheYaXxE

Comment: Checking https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video may helpful for you

Comment: Thank you very much. Found a solution in there :D